# jQuery access vaules of global variable form one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working in jQuery and I have a variable that I declared as global in one function and when I alert it it gives me right result but now I want to access the same variable in another function and alert it in another function it gives me empty result mean I cannot access it over there. I know about the scope of a variable but to overcome it I decleared variable as global but I am still unable to access it.

Here is my first function:

```
 var employee_email = '';
 function showCustomer()
 {
 // fire off the request to ajax_stufflist.php
request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax_stufflist.php?"+url,
    type: "post",
    success: function(data){
        if(data != ''){
    var response = $(data).find("#gmp_stuff").html();
    employee_email = $(data).find(".EMP_EMAIL>span").html();
    //alert(employee_email);
    $("#user_responses").html(response);
      $(function() {
            $("#user_responses").dialog({
                dialogClass:'transparent',
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                modal: true,

                width: 1000,
                autoOpen: false,
                overlay: { opacity: 0 }
            });

  $('#user_responses').dialog('open');
  $('#user_responses').css('display','');


    });
        }
  },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
        $("#user_responses").html('error occured');
    }
  });

}
```

In this function the variable employee_email is decleared above the function and I want to access the same variable with value in other function just next to it in same script tag.

```
function sendEmail(){
alert(employee_email );
request = $.ajax({
    url: "send_email.php?"+employee_email ,
    type: "post",
    success: function(data){
    $("#email_responses").html();


    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
        $("#email_responses").html('error occured');
    }
  });
 }
```

Kindly tell me what's wrong with it. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: well ajax is ASYNC.. the only way to get the  variable inside `sendEmail` function is to call it inside the ajax complete of the first one.. and yes **YOU DON"T NEED READY FUNCTION INSIDE A FUNCTION CALLBACK**

Comment: sorry bipen i am not getting the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of scope. If it would have been, you would have got an error in your console. But you are getting an empty result because either the AJAX call is not complete yet or it has not been able to change the value due to some error there. Try this.
Define:

```
var flag = false;
```

Your success function should be:

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data != '') {
                    var response = $(data).find("#gmp_stuff").html();
                    employee_email = $(data).find(".EMP_EMAIL>span").html();
                    //alert(employee_email);
                    $("#user_responses").html(response);
                    //$(function () {
                    $("#user_responses").dialog({
                        dialogClass: 'transparent',
                        resizable: false,
                        draggable: false,
                        modal: true,

                        width: 1000,
                        autoOpen: false,
                        overlay: { opacity: 0 }
                    });

                    $('#user_responses').dialog('open');
                    $('#user_responses').css('display', '');
                    //});
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
```

And `sendEmail()` can be:

```
function sendEmail(){
    if(flag)
    {
        request = $.ajax({
            url: "send_email.php?"+employee_email ,
            type: "post",
            success: function(data){
                $("#email_responses").html();
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("failure");
                $("#email_responses").html('error occured');
            }
        });
    }
    else
        alert('Sending email is unavailable currently. PLease try after some time.');
}
```

Comment: yes u are right but in my case its not the correct as first function call is on page load but the second function call is infact on button click after first one loads. so do u think it will work then

Comment: yes u are right it was not a problem of scope and was turning arround scope thats y i couldnt solve it well u did it thaks again

Answer (score 1):

Even though this have been answered hundreds of times on SO, I can give you a short explanation.

Since you're dealing with 2 asynchronous calls, you can never access data from the first call in a normal syncronous flow.

Make your first function return your `$.ajax`

```
function showCustomer(){
    return $.ajax({ /* ... */ });
```

And access the data returned in a callback:

```
showCustomer().done(function(data){
    console.log($(data).find(".EMP_EMAIL>span").html());
});
```

This assumes that you're using jQuery 1.5 or above, where the ajax calls exposes a promise.

An other alternative would be to nest the ajax calls (call the second one in the first ones success handler).

Answer (score 1):

You're updating the value employee_email through AJAX call. As soon as first function is called, it makes AJAX call and moves to second function. The second function won't see the value change yet and employee_email doesn't change at all.
You've 2 options -

- Use second function in done of first function.
- Use [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) object in first call and on done of it call the second function.

Comment: but my first function call is on page load and second call is on button click. first call return data in jquery ui dialog which contain button as well each customer so if admin want to send email to any one among all customers he just click the button and send him the email